# what is the most efficient way of checking the greater than and less then in Java?

Tags: java, compare

what is the most efficient way of checking this:

```
A is scheduled for 4 - 7;
B is scheduled for 5 - 8;
```

the schedule above overlaps. How do I check in Java if A and B overlaps or not in the following example:

For A

```
int start = 4;
int end = 7;
```

For B

```
int start = 5;
int end = 8;
```

please advise the most efficient way to check if overlaps. 
thank you

Comment: How have you done for now?

Comment: Like C-like languages, there is not "special" way to do this -- one must test each bound individually.

Comment: Do you have an example of what you doing right now to overcome this?

Comment: I have just compared the start of A with end of B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most efficient way is to use [interval tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree#With_an_Interval).

Answer (score 1):

The below logic should work to test overlap. This is a negative discrete check working backwards from End date. Other ways to check is to take a reference starting time like data.getTime()

```
private boolean testOverlap(Date sched1Start, Date sched1End, Date sched2Start, Date sched2End) {

    //Validate ranges to check if End dates are after start dates

    //Overlaps if both schedules end at same time
    if(sched1End.equals(sched2End)) return true;

    //Get which one ends last
    if(sched1End.before(sched2End)) {

        //Working backwards sched2 starts after sched1 Ends so they dont overlap
        if(sched2Start.after(sched1End) || sched2Start.equals(sched1End)) {
            //Doesnt overlap
            return false;
        }

    } else {
        //Sched1 ends last
        if(sched1Start.after(sched2End) || sched1Start.equals(sched2End)) {
            //Doesnt overlap
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just do with a few data, then even just comparing the starts and the ends is fast enough. However, if you are dealing with a big data, you may want to use some other data structure like augmented tree here to gain some efficiency.